# Vector forces equilibrium

Tags: calculus

Two forces, represented by the vectors $\vec f=2\vec i-8\vec j$ and $\vec g=5\vec i-4\vec j$ are acting on an object. Give a vector $\vec h$ representing the force that must be applied to the object if it is to remain stationary.

Comment: If an object (any object ever, in the history of Newtonian mechanics) is to remain stationary, what does that say about the collection of forces that act upon it?

Comment: You should change the title of the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply note that, for [Newton's first law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion#Newton's_first_law), the resulting force $\vec r$ must be equilibrated by $\vec h$:

$$\vec r=\vec f+\vec g=2\vec i-8\vec j+5\vec i-4\vec j=7\vec i-12\vec j\implies \vec h=-\vec r=-7\vec i+12\vec j$$